# Injecting DAO and Factory in Quartz Job

Tags: java, cdi, weld

i Have a job which needs both a dao and 1 factory class
something like this

https://pastebin.com/kK7VcbW1

My question is how to inject them , i get this exception when the code reaches the dao calling `getSomething` in the Factory class

In the abstractDao i `@Inject entityManager` which i get from an `@ApplicationScoped EnttityManagerProducer` its `getEntityManager` is `@RequestScoped`

```
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:691)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:89)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:164)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.getIfExists(ContextualInstance.java:63)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:83)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:99)
at org.jboss.weldx.persistence.EntityManager$1070085530$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.org.dao.impl.ConcreteDAOImpl.getByName(ConcreteDAOImpl.java:18)
at com.org.dao.impl.ConcreteDAOImp$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getByName(Unknown Source)
at com.org.FactoryImpl.getObj(FactoryImpl.java:33)
```

(the real classes i replaced for the sake of the example)

I tried putting the annotations on both class and interface level i dont know which is preferrable

Comment: You need to manually start the `RequestContext` (provided by Weld implementation) because Quartz start its own thread.

Answer (score 1):

This type of functionality is built in out of the box with Apache Deltaspike, you can read about the [scheduler module](http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/scheduler.html).  The problem as you're aluding to is that by default, contexts are not started automatically when outside of Java EE.  To do that, you need to manually start one.  In CDI 2.0 this can be done by adding `@ActivateRequestContext` to a method/class and a request scope will be started for the duration of that method.

Prior to CDI 2.0, its platform specific.  DeltaSpike solves the issue much cleaner.

Comment: so i need to annotate the getEntityManager method like this                               `@RequestScoped @Produces @ActivateRequestContext getEntityManager() ` ?

Comment: I would put it on the quartz job you're using.  However, are you sure you're using CDI 2.0? What version of weld are you using?

Comment: I am using CDI 2.0 , it works on DAO level but i`ll try your approach seems better